# How to create a php form and integrate a push notification system linked to Telegram or Whatsapp?

Tags: php, push-notification, notifications, telegram, telegram-bot

We have been given a group project by our Web design teacher where he asks us to create a php form to collect data from some students and their grades. the system is supposed to input the data(Student Name, phone number, Study level,  GPA) in a database and to send to the administrators some instant notification containing the freshly entered data. Is there a way to integrate a notification system that would work with a messaging app like Telegram or Whatsapp and would send all the data as soon as they are entered to a Whatsapp or Telegram group?

We designed the form in php and html but for some reason, it auto-submits on the page opening and as a result, we already get empty fields error messages as we open the page which is not good in an aesthetic point of view. The second issue is that we don't know how to send a message from the form to Telegram or Whatsapp. Since our first attempt to solve the problem is very different from what we were asked to do, We decided to remove buggy parts and post the essential basic code with our set of variables so you can help with more accuracy.

```
<?php
//Debug mode on

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Fetch session last typed data
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '');
$_SESSION['phone'] = (isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '');
$_SESSION['gpa'] = (isset($_POST['gpa']) ? $_POST['gpa'] : '');
$_SESSION['type'] = (isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : '');

//Define Errors
$name_err ='Veuillez entrer le nom';
$phone_err = 'Veuillez entrer le numéro de telephone';
$gpa_err = 'Veuillez entrer le gpa';
$type_err ='Veuillez entrer le type';

//Define Placeholders
$name_ph ='name';
$phone_ph = 'Numéro de téléphone';
$gpa_ph = 'Entrez le gpa';
$type_ph ='le type';

// Vars fetch data from form for email and form use

    $name = (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '');
    $phone = (isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '');
    $gpa = (isset($_POST['gpa']) ? $_POST['gpa'] : '');
    $type = (isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : '');

// User ip Address
    $ipadd = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Include db config file
    require_once "db.php";

    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME); 

//Safe database record and telegram or whatsapp message 
This is where I need you help :)

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <br>
    <center><img src="/images/School-Logo.png" alt="school" style="width:123px;height:93px;"></center>
    <link rel="icon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
    <title>Récuperation et envoi de donnes scolaires</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>   
</head>
<body>
   <center> 
        <h1>School system</h1>
        <h3>Collecting Storing data and sending notifications</h3>

        <div class="wrapper">
        <!––  Informations -->
            <div class="studentform">

                <b>
                    Note:
                    <br>
                <ul>

                 <li>Entrez les informations</li>
                 <br>


                </ul>
                </b>

            </div>
            <br>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" id="stud" method="post">

            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($name_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <p align="left">Name <?php echo $name; ?> <font color="red">*</font> </p>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $name_ph;?>" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $name_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($phone_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <p align="left">Contact <?php echo $phone; ?> <font color="red">*</font></p>
                <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $phone_ph;?>" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['phone'];?>" align="left" >
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $phone_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($gpa_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <p align="left">GPA <font color="red">*</font></p>
                <input type="text" name="gpa" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $gpa_ph;?>" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['gpa'];?>" align="left">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $gpa_err; ?></span>
            </div>


             <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($type_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <p align="left">C <font color="red">*</font></p>
                <select name="type" form="stud" class="pickupselect" style="width:100%;">
                <option value="bachelor">Bachelor</option>
                <option value="master">Master</option>
                </select>
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $type_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Entrez les informations" align="left">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  </center>  
</body>
<footer>
<center>school data 2019</center>
<br>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't directly send messages via WhatsApp because it does not provide any public API to use. But I think Telegram provide some kind of API to do so check out their official site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A)** For your first part of the question you did not check if form submitted or not; and that way, the top PHP code is executed every time the page loads. for fixing that problem we need to check if form submitted or not:

change the submit button from :

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Entrez les informations" align="left">
```

to:

```
 <input type="submit" name="submitedFrom" class="btn btn-primary" value="Entrez les informations" align="left">
```

The submit button must have a name attribute so that it can be sent via $post variable.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitedFrom']) && is_array($_POST) && !empty($_POST) && $_POST['submitedFrom'] == 'Entrez les informations'){

   // Fetch session last typed data
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['name'] = (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '');
   $_SESSION['phone'] = (isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '');
   $_SESSION['gpa'] = (isset($_POST['gpa']) ? $_POST['gpa'] : '');
   $_SESSION['type'] = (isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : '');

   //Define Errors
   $name_err ='Veuillez entrer le nom';
   .
   .
   .
}
```

This way when form submitted, and after submit button value is sent in the post variable, the form will be submitted.

**B)** For the second part of the question, I assume you know how to add a record in DB. so I explain how to send a message to a Telegram channel so that every member of the channel can see the messages (submitted form data). but I must warn you that it contains a lot of reading and researching. my explanation is just a guide through this process.

**Notice:** You must test your telegram bot on actual server and it does not run in localhost. there are other tools like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) that gives you the ability to test it in your localhost by creating a bound between your local and an artificial temp server.

**Telegram bot init steps:**

1 - First, you must build a bot in bot father of telegram to get a bot token for your bot after naming it

2 - Make a channel and then add the bot to the channel

3 - Give the permission to read and write in the channel options to your bot (this way the bot can send messages into the channel)

4 - Set a webhook to your bot by typing this code in the address bar of a browser:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot-token>/setWebhook?url=<webhook-url>

<bot-token> - bot token get from BotFather on Telegram
<webhook-url> - webhook url in base64
```

By setting a webhook you tell telegram to communicate with the bot through this URL. Actually, you point to a place that your bot logic exists.

5 - With this function you can send messages via bot into channel:

```
define('BOT_TOKEN', <bot-token>);
define('API_URL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . BOT_TOKEN . '/');

function apiRequest($method, $parameters, $token=null) {

    foreach ($parameters as $key => &$val) {
        if (!is_numeric($val) && !is_string($val)) {
            $val = json_encode($val);
        }
    }
    if(empty($token))
        $url = API_URL.$method;
    else
        $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/".$method;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

The method variable is telegram predefined methods to communicate with API. You can see all the list of message send methods [here](https://core.telegram.org/methods#working-with-messages).

With this example you can send a message to the channel :

```
$params = [
'chat_id' => 'channels chat id', 
"text" => 'form data that you want to send', 
]

apiRequest("sendMessage", $params);
```

I hope this would help you, but remember to read the docs carefully before jump into coding.

Comment: Sure `if(isset($_POST['Entrez les informations'])` works?

Comment: @kerbholz When we don't have any controller and redirection and the code process is on the same page, why not?

Comment: Was wondering because there's no field named `'Entrez les informations'`

Comment: @kerbholz yes you are right. my mistake. I thought its the name of the submit button :D

Comment: Thanks a lot you just saved 6 lives

Comment: @AsianCoder9 don't mention it. if the answer is what you need please mark it as best answer please (green check mark). don't forget to give it an upvote. thanks